# Encryption PowerShell script generated by SQL Server Management Studio executes but doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In SSMS I tried adding encryption to columns.   If I do this in the dialog box, the process works and the field is encrypted.   If I try generating a PowerShell script to set the encryption, after many error messages I've finally got the code to execute without error but nothing happens in the database.   This is the generated script with all the defaults and standard things and I'm running PowerShell as an administrator.

```
Import-Module SqlServer
# Set up connection and database SMO objects

$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=`"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`""
$smoDatabase = Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString $sqlConnectionString

# If your encryption changes involve keys in Azure Key Vault, uncomment one of the lines below in order to authenticate:
#   * Prompt for a username and password:
#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -Interactive

#   * Enter a Client ID, Secret, and Tenant ID:
#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -ClientID '<Client ID>' -Secret '<Secret>' -Tenant '<Tenant ID>'

# Change encryption schema

$encryptionChanges = @()

# Add changes for table [dbo].[MyTable]
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName dbo.MyTable.MyField -EncryptionType Randomized -EncryptionKey "CEK_Auto1"

Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges -InputObject $smoDatabase
```

Any ideas why the code runs but doesn't encrypt the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-column-encryption-using-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15

Following the instructions above with some modifications

Run PowerShell as admin

To give permissions in this session for the file to be executed
This should give correct permission

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

To install SQL Server modules so it PowerShell can access it

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
```

View available commands in SqlServer module

```
Get-Command -Module SqlServer
```

If `New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings` isn't visible, copy files from

sqlserver.21.1.18218.nupkg.zip

downloaded from

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18218

to

C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18218

Then run the powershell script using

```
.\test.ps1
```